# Android error: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_bot (aka com.example.chatbot:drawable/ic_bot) not found

Tags: java, android, gradle, chatbot

Getting the error in Build Output when I'm trying to run the app:
ERROR:C:\Users\xxxxxxxx\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatbot\app\src\main\res\layout\bot_msg.xml:18: AAPT: error: resource drawable/ic_bot (aka com.example.chatbot:drawable/ic_bot) not found.

Here's the code in bot_msg.xml:

```
    <!--below widget is for image of bot-->
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_margin="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_bot" />
```

First time posting. Am a beginner.

Comment: you need to add an image named  ic_bot inside a drawable folder which is inside resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android creates a Drawable resource for any of `.png, .jpg, or .gif` files when you save them in the res/drawable/ directory.

In your case:

```
 ..\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatbot\app\src\main\res\drawable\
```

The filename is used as the resource ID.
compiled resource datatype will be Resource pointer to a BitmapDrawable.
and resource reference will be:

In Java: `R.drawable.filename`

In XML: `@[package:]drawable/filename`

The following application code retrieves the image as a Drawable:

```
Resources res = getResources();
Drawable drawable = res.getDrawable(R.drawable.myimage);
```

Comment: I ended up creating ic_bot.xml resource in the drawable but also found sweet vector code for the image.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have an image named `ic_bot` in your project directory
`C:\.....\AndroidStudioProjects\Chatbot\app\src\main\res\drawable\`